# unable to show snackbar in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-snackbar

I am trying to show the `snackbar` inside the fragment but unable to show I have added the code below. I have tried many method to show `snackbar` but I didn't get how to show `snackbar` inside tab layout fragment and I have made `tabLayout` inside `fragment`.

```
class Books : Fragment(), bookadapter.OnBookItemClicklistner {

lateinit var addbooks: FloatingActionButton
lateinit var bookrecyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var bookadapter: bookadapter
lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
var booklist = arrayListOf<Booksmodel>()
lateinit var bookprogressbar: ProgressBar


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false)

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    addbooks = view.findViewById(R.id.booksFAB)
    bookrecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.bookrecyclerview)
    bookrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    bookprogressbar = view.findViewById(R.id.bookprogressbar)
    bookprogressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    databaseReference = database.getReference("Books")


    booklist.clear()

    bookrecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    showbooks()

    addbooks.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(context, Addbooks::class.java))

    }
    if (!isconnected(requireContext())) {
        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "No Internet", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        snackbar.show()

    }
    return view
}
private fun isconnected(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectionmanager: ConnectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkinfo = connectionmanager.activeNetworkInfo
    return networkinfo != null && networkinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
}
}
```

Comment: Move your snackbar logic into the `onViewCreated` method for it to work

Answer (score 0):

As per Fragment lifecycle and [onCreateView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) documentation

> onCreateView: Called to have the fragment instantiate its user interface view. This is optional, and non-graphical fragments can return null.

That's why you can't modify or display any widgets (`Scoped to the current Fragment`) while the screen in the `onCreateView` state as the Fragment will be still initializing the view.

One simple alternative is using the [onViewCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) method. This method is being called after the `onCreateView` method. which insures that the `view` has already been created.

### BooksFragment.kt

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if (!isconnected(requireContext())) {
            val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "No Internet", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            snackbar.show()

        }
    }
```